# Read/Write to a Cognito Users S3 Bucket via Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a React Amplify site with Storage and a Cognito user pool. When a user on my application uploads a picture it triggers a lambda function that modifies the picture and writes it to a public S3 bucket not related to the Amplify bucket I created. I want to update my lambda function to write the file back into their own personal path associated with the Amplify Storage I setup. I want to get rid of the public S3 bucket altogether.

I am currently utilizing boto3 functions assuming I know the name of the Bucket Key path like this:

`bucket.upload_file(Lambda Temp Location , User Bucket Item Key)`

I had a custom function to upload their files to a public S3 bucket, but in switching to the storage I setup with Amplify I noticed that the bucket names are unique to the user. Researching online I checked the IAM role permissions and I see that the bucket key path looks like this below.

```
private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}
```

How can I get the ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} into my lambda function? I thought I could use the Sub id to append to the link but it doesn't match what I see in S3. I was thinking of sending this detail if possible from my js script to the API call or getting that info within the Lambda itself via matching to user attributes or something... Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It represents IdentityID from the credentialsProvider. You can check: https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSCore/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html